# Sending data throgh NamedPipe when server is down

Tags: c#, named-pipes

I was wondering how to handle a situation where you successfully connected two processes through named pipe (one server and one client), and suddenly (for some reason) the server process ends.

What happens to the pipe? Does it close?
What happens to information being sent by the client to the server? Does it get lost?
How can the client know if the server is down?

All The Best,

Gil

Comment: If you are really worried about this, you should look into using WCF with Message Queue.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `System.IO.Pipes` and `NamedPipeServerStream` for example, you would get IOException when a pipe is broken or disconnected.

When you are using `NamedPipeClientStream` for reading in information from server, I believe the client would wait till a connection is established on the `NamedPipeClientStream.Connect()` call alternative you could use  `NamedPipeClientStream.Connect(Int32)` option to timeout a connection after a predetermined period. Apart from that the `StreamReader.ReadLine()` is also capable of throwing `IOException` when something does not go well.

The `NamedPipeClientStream.IsConnected` would be a simple way to determine if the client is connected successfully to the server or if it is disconnected, closed, or broken.